# SQL Server - Skip querying a database if it is in RESTORING state

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this script that I found online and have adapted to my database instance. What it does is looks to see if a specific table exists in all the SQL Server databases within the instance. If the table is found and if not empty then it will list the name of the database where the table was found. Its all good so far however, if a database is in Restoring state then my script gets stuck at that database. I tried a different options such as STATE = 0 (which is ONLINE) or state_desc != 'RESTORING' in the 'Where' clause but it still fails. The databases in Restoring state isn't the worry here as sometimes someone may be genuinely trying to restore. All I want to do is not to query that database if its not ONLINE. I wanted to somehow make use of SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('DatabaseName', 'Status') but can't figure out how. I am not a T-SQL master, so really hoping if someone can tweak this query just to skip the DBs in Restoring state. This will be much appreciated, thank you..

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temptbl') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temptbl  
CREATE TABLE #temptbl ([COUNT] INT , SiteDBName VARCHAR(50) ) 
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50)  
SELECT @TableName = '[dbo].[PRJMGTLocation]'  
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)  
SELECT @SQL = STUFF( 
        (     SELECT CHAR(13) + 'SELECT ''' + name + ''', COUNT(1) FROM [' + name + '].' + @TableName    
        FROM sys.databases     
        WHERE OBJECT_ID(name + '.' + @TableName) IS NOT NULL   
        --  and STATE = 0 and state_desc != 'RESTORING'   
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')  

INSERT INTO #temptbl (SiteDBName, [COUNT])              

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL  

SELECT * FROM #temptbl t where COUNT >=1 ORDER BY SiteDBName asc
```

Comment: FYI, syntax like `[' + SomeValue + ']'` is *not* injection safe. Use `QUOTENAME` to properly delimit identify your object names. Also I would *assume* that the object (in this case `dbo.PRJMGTLocation`) is likely to be parametrised? if so, then store the table and schema name in 2 different variables and inject them each individually quoted (with `QUOTENAME` again).

Comment: thanks for that tip @Larnu. I will try to use QUOTENAME as advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following slight tweak:

```
select SQL = Stuff( 
    (select Char(13) + 'SELECT ''' + name + ''', COUNT(1) FROM ' + QuoteName(name) + '.' + @TableName    
    from (select top(1000) name from sys.databases  where state=0   )d
    where Object_Id(d.name + '.' + @TableName) is not null   
    for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

The issue is that the filtering out of rows from sys.databases is happening *after* the `object_id()` lookup, using a row-goal in a sub-query can coerce SQL Server to do it in reverse.

Comment: Many thanks for quick reply. I used this tweak and the query is not erroring but its no longer returning any records. I will see if I can find anything...

Comment: I've tried your query on a SQL Server instance using a sample tablename I know exists and it's returning the expected list of aggregated SQL statements for me. Try breaking it down, check what is returned by the inner query and manually check the expected table exists.

Comment: yes, so it is returning aggregating statements for me too. but I wanted to insert those rows into the #temptbl as below: Will see what I can do. basically now the table is somehow coming as empty.. 
INSERT INTO #temptbl (SiteDBName, [COUNT])              

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL  

SELECT * FROM #temptbl t where COUNT >=1 ORDER BY SiteDBName asc

Comment: I think you have multiple issues here, the subject of your question with only using *online* databases I think is answered; executing the dynamic SQL is something else - I think you might need to create a single query using *union* - however there's also better ways eg using *sys.partition_stats* so you might consider this specific issue resolved and ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @stu. Not sure why but I used a second adaptation of the query I had and added the tweak in it. After that the SQL query started returning the values. Many thanks.